# Finding important features in a random forest is very slow

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a set of feature vectors associated with binary class labels,
each of which has about 40,000 features. I train a RandomForest classifier using `RandomForestClassifier` from `sklearn` which takes about 10 minutes. I would however like to see which are the most important features.

I tried simply printing out `clf.feature_importances_` but this takes
about 1 second per feature making about 40,000 seconds overall (approx 12 hours). This
is much much longer than the time needed to train the classifier in
the first place!

Is there a more efficient way to find out which features are most important?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
for i in xrange(len(clf.feature_importances_)):
    print clf.feature_importances_[i]
```

Comment: Based on personal experience and with that number of features, I suggest you give Spark MLlib a shot.

Comment: @ahajib Thank you but why should finding the important features take so much longer than building the classifier itself? Also, have you tried xgboost? Maybe that is better for finding important features?

Comment: Could you post a part of your code? As long as I know, `feature_importances_` returns an array of size n where n is the number of your features and each value indicates the feature importance. I'm not sure what you mean by this taking 1sec per feature.

Comment: @ahajib Added an example. Each new feature takes about 1 second to be printed. Is it recomputing the entire array each time maybe?

Comment: Yep that would be the problem. Did not see this before posting the answer. Btw, I suggest you write the results into a file rather than printing them cause normally a print has its own delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to store the results of `clf.feature_importances_` in an array and then use that to print out results. Like:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

featureImportance = clf.feature_importances_
for i in xrange(len(featureImportance)):
    print featureImportance[i]
```

The way you are handling it right now is recalculating the array every single time.

Comment: Thank you. This is somehow obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Sure. That's why I asked you to post your code. Sometimes we just miss the obvious. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a small variation, which should solve the problem automatically, because it obtains `feature_importances_` just one:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
for feature_importance in clf.feature_importances_:
    print feature_importance
```

If you need the loop index `i` elsewhere in your loop, just use `enumerate`:

```
for i, feature_importance in enumerate(clf.feature_importances_):
    print feature_importance
```

This is also the more Pythonic way than using

```
for i in xrange(len(<some-array>)): 
    <some-array>[i]
```

---

I think it would have been better if somehow the `RandomForestClassifier` keeps track of its state behind the scenes. If the state changes (e.g., `n_estimators` is changed, or another parameter), it should recompute `feature_importances_` (on the fly, as it does now). Otherwise, it should just return the current, cached, feature importances.
That is, however, more complicated behind the scenes.

Perhaps the simplest would have been to change the property into an actual method: `calc_feature_importances()`.
Then again, I didn't put the effort in into creating `RandomForestClassifier`, so I can't really complain.